# Getting last_day of date is giving error as ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Tags: oracle, datetime

I have a date in some format and from that I want only the `last_Day` of that month. SO below is relative information.

`V_BILLEND_DT = 2022-12-31T00:00:00+05:30`

And I am trying like this.

`select to_char(last_day(V_BILLEND_DT),'dd') into V_updatMonth from dual;`

But getting error as

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Comment: What's the data type of `V_updatMonth`?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan: it is `nvarchar2(100);`

Comment: `last_day()` function needs a date type argument, you can convert that timestamp value to date by using `trunc()` such as `to_char(last_day(trunc(v_biilend_dt)))`. Btw, I presume that variable is quoted as `'2022-12-31T00:00:00+05:30'`

Comment: tried like this `select to_char(last_day(trunc('2022-12-31T00:00:00+05:30')))  from dual;` and getting error as `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER`

Comment: yes its also sting. but I have made it like this. can u please help with it

Comment: OK you may refer the present answer, good luck

Comment: If `V_BILLEND_DT` is a string in the format you showed then Littlefoot's answer works; if it is a timestamp with time zone with that value (and your NLS settings add the 'T') then your original code works - though you can assign directly without querying `dual`. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MkHmFqAu). It can't be a date as it had a time zone offset. So what are you doing differently? Please edit the question to add a [mre].

Comment: Nad: there's no need to add "please help" to your questions and/or your comments. Readers may find it needy, and downvote as a consequence. Please read: [How can we encourage (new) authors to ask confident questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366264/how-can-we-encourage-new-authors-to-ask-confident-questions)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to, don't keep *date* values as strings. Nothing good in that, only trouble.

```
SQL> create table test (v_billend_dt nvarchar2(100));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test values ('2022-12-31T00:00:00+05:30');

1 row created.
```

If all values follow the same format, then the first 10 characters represent date value; the rest doesn't matter for what you want to extract, and that's the last day of the month represented by that string. Therefore:

```
SQL> select last_Day(to_date(substr(v_billend_dt, 1, 10), 'yyyy-mm-dd')) from test;

LAST_DAY(
---------
31-DEC-22

SQL>
```

This (`31-DEC-22`) is date represented by format my database returns by default. You can `TO_CHAR` it with another format model, if you want; or, you can `alter session` and set different format. But - what you wanted - is here: that's the *last day*.

---

You commented that you want to get `31` as result; as I said in my last sentence: use `to_char` with desired format model:

```
SQL> select to_Char(last_Day(to_date(substr(v_billend_dt, 1, 10), 'yyyy-mm-dd')), 'dd') from test;

TO
--
31

SQL>
```

Comment: I want only `31` in `V_updatMonth`

Comment: I tried like this `select to_char(last_Day(to_date(substr(V_BILLEND_DT, 1, 10), 'yyyy-mm-dd')), 'dd') into V_updatMonth from dual;` but its not working

Comment: the error is `ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected`

Comment: Also my `v_billend_dt ` is `date`

Comment: @Nad - it can't be a *date* if it has an offset, which you've shown as +05:30. So is it a string as you've also suggested in comments, or timestamp with time zone? Please edit your question to show how both variables are actually declared and populated - preferably as a simple but complete anonymous block, i.e. a [mre].